# F#: Unable to inherit from List<'T> in F# interactive

Tags: list, f#, interactive, sealed

```
  >     type XList<'T> (_collection : seq<'T>) =
            inherit List<'T> (_collection)
            member this.Add _item = if not <| this.Contains _item then base.Add _item
            new () = XList<'T> (Seq.empty<'T>);;

              inherit List<'T> (_collection)
      --------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(47,9): error FS0945: Cannot inherit a sealed type
```

My understanding is that List<'T> is actually *not* sealed.  No?

Also, this seems to work just fine outside F# interactive.  That exact code is in my F# project, and the compiler processes it without complaining.  I've got the same thing going on in a couple of C# projects.  The code works as expected in every case.

Normally, I'd just extend List<'T> with a static method (doing it the "F# way"), but hiding List.Add should work fine, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try fully qualifying the type name: `inherit System.Collections.Generic.List<'T> (_collection)`

Comment: Thanks, I knew that S.C.G.List and F# list would bite me in the ass eventually.  Broke my cherry, now.

Answer (score 5):

As others already explained, your code actually tries to inherit from the F# list type (which is sealed). This is a bit confusing, but F# provides an alias `ResizeArray<T>` that stands for the generic .NET `List<T>` type, so you can solve this without using long names too:

```
type XList<'T> (_collection : seq<'T>) = 
  inherit ResizeArray<'T> (_collection)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing your F# interactive has a different set of `open` namespaces than your F# project code?  That is, is this `System.Collections.Generic.List` or what?